# How can I change the port Jetty runs on with the Intellij 2016 plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetty

Normally when I want to change Jetty's port I can do so from the config files.  It appears changing the config files for Jetty does not affect the instance that is created by the Intellij 2016 plugin.

Unlike the Intellij Tomcat plugin there is no place to change the port which jetty runs on.

Since our work blocks port 8080 I have to change this port to something else but have been unable to do so.

EDIT:

I tried changing start.ini in my Jetty directory like so...

[image: Start.ini change]

But it still shows this error when I run/debug jetty from Intellij's plugin.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No method works with the current version of jetty (9.3.9)

the plug-in doesn't seem to have been updated for ages because it had been, it should just allow the selection of a `start.ini` where one can simply config everything you are likely to need.

So, it doesn't matter if you configure it in the `start.ini` in the jetty home directory, or even directly in the `etc/jetty-http.xml`, the plugin will do its own stupid thing and run it on port `8080`.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA indeed always reports Jetty port as 8080 in the output console when Jetty Run/Debug Configuration starts. But it uses in fact the port which was specified in configuration file. We have open issue about this inconsistency: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-153406 .

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set it directly in the plugin itself. You can, however, set it in your Jetty Server installation folder.

1. locate start.ini file inside the Jetty folder
2. Uncomment line `# jetty.http.port=8080` (remove # sign)
3. Change he port number to different value eg. `jetty.http.port=8081`
4. Save the file

Now when you run the jetty from idea, it should have the port you set in the config file.

Comment: I updated my question to show it still fails when I try this.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Jetty are you using?
As Vojtech has mentioned, this cannot be done within the plugin.
What I am currently doing, so I can run two projects at the same time is, have one Jetty instance as 8080 as the distribution comes as and then have another distribution downloaded and change the etc/jetty.xml file to the following:

```
<Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="8085"/></Set>
```

I've also changed a few other spots where 8080 is referenced in the xml's.
jetty-fileserver.xml, jetty-spdy-proxy.xml and jettyspdy.xml

This is working on Jetty 7.6.14, hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

i found this item on plugin of jetty in intellyj folder
[jettyPlugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBhJ7.png)

then in star.ini file i set jetty.port=8080
[Start.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sb7xG.png)

and my server star at 8085 port